# The difference between systems with and without direct feedthrough

Tags: nonlinear, kalman-filter, state-space-models

Generally, in nonlinear state estimation the state space model is defined by the following pair of difference equations in discrete-time:

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
x_k & = f(x_{k-1},u_{k-1},\theta)+q_{k-1}\\
y_k & = h(x_k,u_{k},\theta)+r_k
\end{aligned} 
\end{equation}

Can some one explain the difference between a nonlinear system with direct feedthrough and a nonlinear system without direct feedthrough, and to what genere belong the first system (generally used), if possible some references?

**system with direct feedthrough:**
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
x_{k+1} & = f(x_{k},u_{k},\theta)+q_{k-1}\\
y_k & = h(x_k,u_{k},\theta)+r_k
\end{aligned} 
\end{equation}

**system without direct feedthrough:**
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
x_{k+1} & = f(x_{k},u_{k},\theta)+q_{k-1}\\
y_k & = h(x_k,\theta)+r_k
\end{aligned} 
\end{equation}